# abntex and hyphenat problems in url formatting

Tags: bibtex, hyperref, hyphenation, abnt

**Problem**

I would like to disable all hyphenation within the document, but I want the bibtex URL entries to be properly hyphenated, and also properly linked according to the `hyperref` package. Because of this I'm having some issues using `abntex` bibliography formatting with the `\usepackage[none]{hyphenation}` call.

**Example**

This bibtex entry:

```
@ARTICLE{Engelhardt2008,
  author = {Sebastian Engelhardt},
  title = {The Economic Properties of Software},
  journal = {Jena Economic Research Papers},
  year = {2008},
  volume = {45},
  url = {http://zs.thulb.uni-jena.de/servlets/MCRFileNodeServlet/jportal_derivate_00119979/wp_2008_045.pdf}
}
```

Placed in a document like this:

```
\documentclass{abnt}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{abnt-UFPR}
\usepackage{abntcite}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}

\begin{document}
  \sloppy
  \cite{Engelhardt2008}
  \bibliography{test.bib}
\end{document}
```

Will make `abntex` format the following bibitem:

```
\bibitem[Engelhardt 2008]{Engelhardt2008}
\abntrefinfo{Engelhardt}{ENGELHARDT}{2008}
{ENGELHARDT, S. The economic properties of software.
\emph{Jena Economic Research Papers}, v.~45, 2008.
Dispon{\'\i}vel em:
  \htmladdnormallink{$<$http:\-/\-/zs\-.thulb\-.uni-jena\-.de\-/servlets\-/MCR%
FileNodeServlet\-/jportal\underline{\ }derivate\underline{      }00119979\-/wp\underline{\ }2008\underline{      }045\-.pdf$>$}{http://zs.thulb.uni-jena.de/servlets/MCRFileNodeServlet/jport%
al_derivate_00119979/wp_2008_045.pdf}.}
```

**Output**

That looks like this in the A4 page:

[image: wrong bibitem formatting]

If I remove `\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}` from the preamble, this same entry will have the desired formatting, but the whole text will be hyphenated.

[image: right bibitem formatting]

**Workarounds Tried**

Using `\usepackage[hyphens]{url}` will output this on compilation:

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package url.
```

I could also use just `\usepackage{url}` and change all my bibtex entries `url` params to:

```
 note = {Disponível em: $<$\url{http://zs.thulb.uni-jena.de/servlets/MCRFileNodeServlet/jportal_derivate_00119979/wp_2008_045.pdf}$>$}
```

But I really wouldn't like to do this, as I'm using a bibliography manager to generate the `.bib` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try putting

```
\renewcommand{\-}{\penalty 0 }
```

just before the bibliography. However, it's very questionable that the bibliography style loaded by `abnt` does such horrible things to URLs, when it's simply sufficient to input them as `\url{...}` when the `url` package is loaded.

This won't give hyphens at break points (which is in my opinion the right thing to do, as it's impossible for the reader to distinguish between real or added hyphens).

However, I find it questionable also inhibiting hyphenation on a global basis.

A different strategy than using `hyphenat` can be saying

```
\begin{document}
\hyphenrules{nohyphenation}\exhyphenpenalty 10000
```

and

```
\hyphenrules{brazilian}\exhyphenpenalty 50
```

before the bibliography, in order to allow hyphenation in it. The parameter `\exhyphenpenalty` is used by TeX to decide whether break a line after an explicit hyphen in the document (a compound word, for instance); setting it to 10000 inhibits the feature; 50 is the usual value. The `nohyphenation` pseudolanguage has no hyphenation rule.

Comment: Thanks @egreg. That worked great. The `abntex` package haven't been updated for some years, and still is the most complete package for the ABNT patterns. I will try to suggest these changes. And what would be the best solution to stop text hyphenation instead of doing it globally?

Comment: @ViniciusMassuchetto Why should hyphenation be inhibited to begin with?

Comment: It's just a matter of preference.

Comment: @ViniciusMassuchetto Languages like Portuguese or Italian that have generally long words (with respect to English, for instance) receive great benefit from hyphenation, which makes for better typeset paragraphs.

Comment: I understand that, even if most of the ABNT formatted documents by other editors have hyphenation disabled. I asked it because I couldn't find a `\hyphenationon` and a `\hyphenationoff` commands on the `hyphenat` package documentation.